# How to make postfix sign non-delivery notifications with DKIM?

Tags: email, postfix, dkim, email-bounces, opendkim

I have set up my "postfix" server to sign outgoing messages with DKIM and verified that it works correctly for SMTP users using authentication. However, "non-delivery notifications", i.e. mails that are sent automatically from the server itself, are not being signed and are therefore rejected by some recipients during forwarding. What system exactly sends those messages, via which channel and how can I change the configuration to make sure they are also signed?

The DKIM-related part of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

The OpenDKIM configuration file `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```
Syslog                yes
Logwhy                yes
UMask                 007

Canonicalization      relaxed/simple
Mode                  sv
SubDomains            no

AutoRestart           yes
AutoRestartRate       10/1M
Background            yes
DNSTimeout            5
SignatureAlgorithm    rsa-sha256

Socket                local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock

PidFile               /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

OversignHeaders       From

TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

UserID                opendkim

KeyTable              refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable          refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table

ExternalIgnoreList    /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

InternalHosts         /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
```

Most of the headers of a non-delivery notification that did make it to its destination (despite not being signed):

```
Return-Path: <>
X-Original-To: mail@otherdomain.com
Delivered-To: mail@otherdomain.com
Received: from mail.primary-domain.com
    by mail.otherdomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id CC9F8BB862
    for <mail@otherdomain.com>; [...date removed...]
Received: by mail.primary-domain.com (Postfix)
    id 1073CBB8A8; [...date removed...]
Date: [...removed...]
From: MAILER-DAEMON@primary-domain.com (Mail Delivery System)
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
To: mail@otherdomain.com
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="D80F1BB862.1696269305/mail.primary-domain.com"
Message-Id: <20231002175505.1073CBB8A8@mail.primary-domain.com>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

`/etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1
localhost

.otherdomain.com
.primary-domain.com
```

`/etc/opendkim/signing.table`:

```
*@otherdomain.com      default._domainkey.otherdomain.com
*@*.otherdomain.com    default._domainkey.otherdomain.com
*@primary-domain.com   default._domainkey.primary-domain.com
*@*.primary-domain.com default._domainkey.primary-domain.com
```

### Update

On suggestion of @NikitaKipriyanov I increased the log level:

```
Syslog                  yes
LogWhy                  yes
MilterDebug             9
```

Weirdly, this didn't produce any logs about any outgoing message (neither the "normal" messages, which are being signed correctly, nor the NDNs, which are not being signed).

Comment: NDNs are generated internally and given directly to the `cleanup` process in Postfix. It is the process `non_smtpd_milters` setting belongs to. It seems all is set up correctly on the Postfix side; can you increase debugging in OpenDKIM: enable `LogWhy`, increase `MilterDebug`, and attach generated logs?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you! I made the changed you suggested. Weirdly, this didn't produce any additional log entries. Neither the (correctly signed) "normal" outgoing messages nor the NDNs appear in the logs. Only the verification of incoming messages is shown in the log.

Comment: Do you have `SyslogSuccess yes` also? `MilterDebug` didn't produce any output? Where did you look? You hadn't specified a distro. In a Debian system you look into at least `/var/log/mail.log`, `/var/log/debug`, `/var/log/daemon.log`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I've looked in all of them. The logs about the incoming messages appear in "/var/log/mail.log". However, there was nothing about outgoing messages. Now, with "SyslogSuccess yes" I see a single line ("DKIM-Signature field added (s=default, d=primary-domain.com)") about "normal" outgoing messages, but not about the NDNs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading [Postfix MILTER Readme](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#non-smtp-milters) more carefully I found this paragraph:

> Signing internally-generated bounce messages
>
> Postfix normally does not apply content filters to mail that is generated internally such as bounces or Postmaster notifications. Filtering internally-generated bounces would result in loss of mail when a filter rejects a message, as the resulting double-bounce message would almost certainly also be blocked.
>
> To sign Postfix's own bounce messages, enable filtering of internally-generated bounces (line 2 below), and don't reject any internally-generated bounces with non_smtpd_milters, header_checks or body_checks (lines 3-5 below).
>
> ```
> 1 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
> 2     internal_mail_filter_classes = bounce
> 3     non_smtpd_milters = don't reject internally-generated bounces
> 4     header_checks = don't reject internally-generated bounces
> 5     body_checks = don't reject internally-generated bounces
> ```

It turns out, this is likely a problem with Postfix configuration. Set in `main.cf`:

```
internal_mail_filter_classes = bounce
```

On the other hand, the [`man postconf`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#internal_mail_filter_classes) page has the following warning regarding this option:

> NOTE: It's generally not safe to enable content inspection of Postfix-generated email messages. The user is warned.

I think the purpose of the warning is to remind again that milter **must not REJECT** a message. Make sure it only signs.

Comment: +1, stellar answer! Not only did it do the trick (NDNs are being signed now), but it references the relevant sources and explains the issue well. And shame on me for not having read the postfix manual properly myself!

Comment: Me too :) there's always a bit of it you don't know, even if you think you've read all of its documentation many times.